# Limit bandwidth on a Mikrotik router by port number?

Tags: mikrotik, bandwidth-control

I have this one Mikrotik router (RB951G-2HnD) that serves as a main router with port forwarding for HTTP/HTTPS and Plex to a server behind NAT. Now since there isn't much upload bandwidth (15Mbps), I'd love to limit the bandwith for HTTP/HTTPS on the WAN interface so that there's some bandwidth left for Plex. I've been looking in `/queue` but haven't seen anything that limits by port number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described here

- http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Traffic_Priortization,_RouterOS_QoS_Implemetation

  or here
- http://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=73214

First you need to mark your packets. And to mark you can use port number

```
/ip firewall mangle
add action=mark-packet chain=forward dst-port=80 new-packet-mark=http passthrough=no protocol=tcp
add action=mark-packet chain=forward dst-port=443 new-packet-mark=https passthrough=no protocol=tcp
```

And then you can do traffic shaping on those marked packets

Below is also a very good and simple example

http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/TransparentTrafficShaper

Comment: I added a queue and apply it to the WAN interface:
    /queue simple add name="wan-https-limit" target=pppoe-out1 max-limit=10M/10M

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a `mangle` rule in `/ip firewall` that will match outgoing packets to ports 80 and 443 and mark them (`action=mark-packet`).

Then you can create a queue and use the packet mark you defined on the mangle rule to match and limit those packets.